# How to call Redirect() inside a private method, that is called by a Controller Action?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

**THE GOAL: invoke a Redirect from inside a private method, that's called by an executing Action.**

SETUP: we have this private method, inside a Controller, and **we need to redirect on any raised error:**

[EDIT: please note - the first example here is the problem to be solved (if it is possible) for this post]

```
private void CleanLoginData(ref object logindata)
{
   try
   {
      logindata.Trim(); <---fake example of what it might do
   }

   catch (Exception e)
   {
      CustomError ce = ErrorFactory.BuildCustomRedirectError(e)
      Redirect(ce.UrlToErrorPage);
   }
}
```

**this method is called by an Action inside the same Controller, in the context of a PostRedirectGet op:**

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> LogIn(object loginData)
{
   CleanLoginData(ref loginData);
   await DbAgent.LoginAsync(loginData);
   Redirect("~/loggedin");
}
```

but this fails. MVC ignores the Redirect inside CleanLoginData and still calls 'DbAgent.LoginAsync()'.

also, this one fails as well, if we move the try/catch from inside the method to outside:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> LogIn(object loginData)
{
   try
   {
      CleanLoginData(loginData);
   }   

   catch (Exception e)
   {
      CustomError ce = ErrorFactory.BuildCustomRedirecdtError(e)
      Redirect(ce.CustomRedirectLink);
   }

   await DbAgent.LoginAsync(loginData);
   Redirect("~/loggedin");
}
```

MVC still calls DbAgent.LoginAsync().  this surprised me.  is there any way to fire a Redirect inside a private method that's called by an Action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't redirect from a void type method but there is a pretty simple solution exist.
set return type of method to bool and return false from catch statement otherwise true and then in controller check if it return false redirect

```
private bool CleanLoginData(ref object logindata)
{
   try
   {
      logindata.Trim(); <---fake example of what it might do
   }

   catch (Exception e)
   {
      return false; // if it throw error
   }
return true; // if it does not throw error
}
```

Now in controller check if your function return true or false. if false then redirect

```
public async Task<IActionResult> LogIn(object loginData)
{
    bool succeed = CleanLoginData(loginData);
    if(!succeed)
    {
      return Redirect("~/loggedin");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, i am aware of this (and other) work arounds, where you use variables to indirectly check if an Exception occured.  however, my goal is to avoid these, if it's possible to have everything cleanly included inside the private method.  i can't find any official documentation on it yet, but i guess it is an unwritten MVC commandment then, that you cannot ever call a Redirect() from inside a separate private method?

Comment: @jägerschmidt you can't from a void type method IActionResult and RedirectResult is a return type that allow you to return redirect response

Comment: **thanks. marked as answer for the inclination that 'it is completely impossible to call a Redirect() from inside a private method.'**  i was hoping there was a way to do this, somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a demo to show redirect on the raised error:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Log()
    {
        string s = "s";
        try
        {
            CleanData(s);
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Redirect("https://www.google.com/");
        }
        return View("Index");
    }
    private void CleanData(string s)
    {
        var a = Int32.Parse(s);
    }
```

result:
[image]

If you want to redirect in private method,It may be like this:

```
private IActionResult CleanData(string s)
        {
            try
            {
                xxxxx
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return Redirect("https://www.google.com/");
            }
            return View("xxx");
            
        }
public IActionResult Log()
        {
            string s = "s";
            CleanData(s);
            return View("Index");
           
        }
```

But then it will redirect in CleanData,whatever it has an error.

Comment: thanks! your first demo is right and i see my error was forgetting to use the 'return' keyword before the Redirect() call.  can't believe i missed that.  my main issue though (for this post) is the problem first stated; namely can a redirect somehow be called from a private method. i tried your second example, which i see only differs from mine by the return type (IActionResult instead of void), but the Redirect still fails to execute on an Exception.

Comment: Yes,the second one is a sample used to illustrate it will only redirect in CleanData.So it will never do `return View("Index");` in public IActionResult Log().It is used to illustrate why the code you shown will not work.The first one is a good choice to work rather than the second one.